# Describe the Riemann surface associated with $w=(z^2-1)^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

I've been asked to describe the Riemann surface associated with the function $w= (z^2-1)^2$. I found the branches to be $\pm 1$, but I am confused about proceeding.

I know if the function were just $w= (z^2-1)$, the corresponding Riemann surface would be 2-sheeted, but for my questions I am confused about whether the surface would be 2-sheeted or 4-sheeted, and how to tell in the future.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It looks entire to me.

Comment: @edm I'm unfamiliar with the term, but looked it up in my book. I now understand what the term means, but would not know how to use that here

Comment: It means the function is simply a holomorphic function on the complex plane. The points $-1$ and $1$ are not branches, but zeroes. No need for any special Riemann surface to describe your function. Unless you are actually thinking of the function $\sqrt{z^2-1}$.

Comment: I see what you mean. I will definitely look into whether or not the question is supposed to be something different, as what you say makes complete sense, as it is just a polynomial. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have copied Exercise 2 from Section 3.4.3 of *Ahlfors*. Some other books use a different definition of Riemann surface, which would render your question meaningless. (Hence some comments that you have already received.)

Let's use Ahlfors' definition here. We want to divide $\mathbb{C}$ into non-overlapping regions so that $f$, when restricted to each region, be a 1-1 mapping.

Let's use a concrete example. Imagine a simple closed curve $z(t)$ that moves from 2, 2i, -2, -2i, and back to 2. You will get $f(z)=9$ four times. This means you need four sheets.

In fact, we can take the four quadrants of the complex plane to be your four fundamental regions.

Below is some modification to my original answer following Maxim's comment. (I went back to the textbooks that I used before. Ahlfors is actually a lot less clear on this than e.g. Needham. So if you are using Ahlfors, please get another book to get a different perspective.)

For the branch points, it is easier to look at $z=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{w}}$.

$w$ needs to go around a small circle around 0 *twice* for $z$ to go around either +1 or -1, depending on which branch you take for the outer square root, once. Therefore $w=0$ is a branch point of order 1.

Similarly, if we take the negative inner square root, $w$ needs to go around a small circle around 1 *twice* for $z$ to go around 0 once. Therefore $w=1$ is also a branch point of order 1. (The other two copies of $w$, corresponding to $z=\pm\sqrt{2}$, are not branching points.)

Finally, $w$ needs to go around a big enough circle, e.g. $|w| = 10$, four times, for $z$ to return to its original value. Therefore $\infty$ is a branching point of order 3.

Comment: $w = 1$ is not a branch point of order $3$. We need to consider what happens when $z$ goes around a critical point or around $\infty$ while remaining in a small neighborhood of that point. $w = 1$ connects only two sheets, the other two copies of $w = 1$ lie on sheets that are isolated in the neighborhood of $w = 1$. $w = 0$ connects one pair of sheets and another copy of $w = 0$ connects another pair of sheets. We have three branch points of order 1 and one branch point ($\infty$) of order 3. It might be clearer to consider $w = 0, 1, \infty$ as the branch points of $\sqrt {1 + \sqrt w}$.

Comment: @Maxim. You are right. I knew something was off when I wrote the original answer. Thank you for clearing it up! I will incorporate your comment in my answer.